# Basic SQL Select statement - How Do I find the Sum?

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate-functions

I want to find the sum and count of specific values in my table.

In my specific situation, the table is called `product`. The column names for the table are `'id`, `product_id`, `quantity` and `shipping_price`.

The table contains: (Based on `SELECT * FROM product;`)

```
product_id:1    quantity:1     end_price:15     shipping_price:1
product_id:2    quantity:2     end_price:15     shipping_price:0
product_id:1    quantity:1     end_price:15     shipping_price:1
product_id:2    quantity:1     end_price:15     shipping_price:0
product_id:1    quantity:1     end_price:15     shipping_price:1
product_id:3    quantity:1     end_price:15     shipping_price:0
```

I need a SQL statement which will select the amount of rows with the same `product_id`, get the sum of the `quantity`, `end_price` and `shipping_price`.

For this example I want the SQL statement to returns, for item 1:

```
product_id:1    quantity:3    end_price:45    shipping_price:3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `SUM` aggregate function, grouping your results by `product_id`.

```
SELECT  product_id,
        SUM(quantity) quantity,
        SUM(end_price) end_price,
        SUM(shipping_price) shipping_price
FROM    product
GROUP BY product_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity), SUM(end_price), SUM(shipping_price) FROM product GROUP BY product_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_id, sum(quantity), sum(end_price), sum(shipping_price) FROM product
group by product_id
```